# How to boost photoshop performance?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have windows 64bit pc with 4GB ram and Intel Pentium 3.00GHz processor.

Now when I worked with lots of groups in PSD and when I move or transform a group, Photoshop slows down.These operations are slower.

I am worked with a lot of screens of Application UI where I just have to move similar components from one to another.

What are the tricks for working efficiently with large groups so that Photoshop quickly works and doesn't slow down?

Comment: 4GB of RAM is very low by today's standards. More RAM would certainly **not** hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and research the [Performance](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/optimize-photoshop-cc-performance.html) tab.
2. Clean up your cache via 'Edit → Purge → All'.
3. Purge 'Camera Raw Cache'.
4. Clean up your documents and work with the correct resolution.
5. Buy an SSD drive.

Comment: I fix for me was running Photoshop + [Ctrl] + [Shift] + [Alt] to delete Preferences. After that magically my Photoshop is running smoothly again.